# Swift compiler slow - why does it always recompile classes with an extension?

Tags: swift, performance

we've been having problems with very slow compile time on our rather big projects. Based on this great article: https://thatthinginswift.com/debug-long-compile-times-swift/ I set my swift compiler flags to:

`-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies`

and started debugging. What I found out was that for every file that is compiled (>200) it also compiles bunch of seemingly unrelated files with it.

After more debugging it seems that if you add to a class or struct any extension like this:

```
extension MasterViewController {
    func someFunc(){
    }
}
```

the class MasterViewController will be compiled with any unrelated file in your target.

In my small example project there is also DetailViewController which is pushed from the MasterViewController. Because MasterViewController has referenced it, it also have to be recompiled with it. Every time for every file.

On this small project, the compile time is still fast but you can see how this can get really slow on big project where the extensions are used in more than  few classes. On our project more than half of the source files is recompiled every time.

To test out the issue download the CompilerTest project from here https://1drv.ms/u/s!Av6oIon-UawdxmUtmDCNWF_zOcjn

Then build the project and go to latest build in Report navigator. After expanding the TestFile.swift you will see that MasterViewController was also compiled even though its not referenced at all in the file.

Then comment out the extension in MasterViewController.swift, clean the project and build folder. Then build again. You will see that the TestFile is now compiled as it should.

My question is whether there is a reason for this behaviour or if it is a bug that should be reported.

Comment: I've noticed this in a couple of projects myself. I think it is a bug!